# How to put percentage progress in blue imp jQuery upload?

Tags: jquery, upload

I'm using the jQuery file upload and its working fine. But the progress bar just loads and most times it gets to the end but the file wouldn't have uploaded finish.

Can anyone help me implement a percentage on the progress bar? It uploads with a text saying upload complete when it's done. Below is my working code.
                        
                          
                          Select Image

```
                      <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
                      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" class="coverimage" multiple>
                      <input type="hidden" id="img_name" class="img_name">
                    </span><br><b>  Recommended image size is 411 by 391, else image will be resized automatically.</b>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="progress" class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>

              </div>
              <div id="pUploadMessage"> </div>
              <font color="#FF0000"> (Please Don’t save until image name appears!) </font>
                <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
                <div id="files" class="files"></div> <br>



                          <script>


                    $(function () {
                        'use strict';
                        // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
                        var url = window.location.hostname === 'clive.org' ?
                                    '//http://tripplegee.ng/admin/' : 'server/php/';
                        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                            url: url,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            done: function (e, data) {
                                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                                    $('#img_name').val(file.name);
                                });
                            },
                            progressall: function (e, data) {
                                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                                    'width',
                                    progress + '%'
                                );
                            }
                        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
                            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
                    });
                    </script>



                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    // this is where the script that would process the input goes to 


                    $(document).ready(function($){
                        images = new Array();
                        $(document).on('change','.coverimage',function(){
                             files = this.files;
                             $.each( files, function(){
                                 file = $(this)[0];
                                 if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                                     var reader = new FileReader();
                                     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                     reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                                        img_src = e.target.result; 
                                        html = "<img class='img-thumbnail' style='width:500px; height:300px ;margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:20px;' src='"+img_src+"'>";
                                        $('#files').html( html );
                                     };
                                 } 
                            });
                        });
                    });

                        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the callback "progress"? I will give you an example below.

```
progress: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    var progressBar = $('#progress').find('.progress-bar_value');
    progressBar.css('width',progress + '%');
    if (progress == 100) {
        // Any custom things here.
    }
}
```